# Syntax of matrix in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, matrix, syntax

I'm new to the VBA Excel. The code works in its current state, yet the comment section produces an error.  Why?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Matrix()
Dim x() As Variant: Dim y As Variant
ReDim x(1 To 2, 1 To 2)
y = 7
x = [{5, 13; 3, 8}]
x(1, 1) = y
'x = [{y, 13; 3, 8}]
End Sub
```

Comment: Square-bracket "evaluate" needs to be passed something that would be meaningful in a worksheet cell  - the "y" is out of scope there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant use the Evaluate Brackets with variables, try it like this:

```
x = Application.Evaluate("{" & y & ", 13; 3, 8}")
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that OP didn't need to include the ReDim, or even to Dim x as an array.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any literature clarifying the differences between brackets?

Comment: YW, some documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate